# parse_str only returning first parameter

Tags: php

So I wrote some code that should simply take this

```
title=title&description=description&image=(some image here)&color=ff0000
```

And return this

```
echo $meta["title"] //title
echo $meta["description"] //description
echo $meta["image"] //(some image here)
echo $meta["color"] //ff0000
```

Instead, it only returns title for some reason...

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $url = substr($url, 2);
    $url = base64_decode($url);
    // title=title&description=description&image=(some image here)&color=ff0000
    // confusing part
    parse_str($url, $meta);
?>
```

Comment: Nope https://3v4l.org/cG0Dp

Comment: what is the reason of having `base64_decode`? remove that line and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about smth like this?

```
$string = 'title=title&description=description&image=(some image here)&color=ff0000';

$array = explode("&", $string);
$finalArray = [];
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    $singleArr = explode("=",$arr);
    $finalArray[$singleArr[0]] = $singleArr[1];
}
print("<pre>".print_r($finalArray,true)."</pre>");
```

Which will print out:

```
Array
(
    [title] => title
    [description] => description
    [image] => (some image here)
    [color] => ff0000
)
```

Instead of reinventing the wheel :)  (thx @u_mulder)

```
$urlString = parse_url($string, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($urlString, $urlArray);
print_r($urlArray["image"]); // Or what ever paramneter, like
foreach($urlArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $urlArray[$key];
}
```

Comment: What about __not inventing the wheel__?

Comment: @u_mulder Agreed :)

Comment: Ok so the only reason I can think of it not working is the amp;?
Im very new to php and I have no idea where the amp; comes from.

If i use the string you provided it works, but when i use my $url string it doesnt.